# How to join two consecutive lines together by awk

Tags: awk

I have a text files with numbers, which I show a chunk of it hear:

```
4194369
4194376
4194383
4194377
4194389
4194394
4194399
4194395
4194402
4194403
4194407
```

I want to join two consecutive numbers in the file together, the following code dose the job for me, except it is not printing the last line, the output of the code is:

```
awk '{printf $0 (NR%2?",":"\n")}' file.txt
4194369,4194376
4194383,4194377
4194389,4194394
4194399,4194395
4194402,4194403
```

I wan to get this as output:

```
4194369,4194376
4194383,4194377
4194389,4194394
4194399,4194395
4194402,4194403
4194407
```

Comment: never do `printf $0`, always use `printf "%s", $0` instead. Consider the difference when $0 contains print formatting characters like `%s`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following.

```
xargs -n 2 < Input_file  | tr -s ' ' ','
```

Output will be as follows.

```
4194369,4194376
4194383,4194377
4194389,4194394
4194399,4194395
4194402,4194403
4194407
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** Trying to correct your attempt in `awk` as follows.

```
awk 'FNR%2==0{print val","$0;val="";next} {val=val?val OFS $0:$0} END{if(val != ""){print val}}'  Input_file
```

What was error in your approach, you are not checking next line's value(either it is present or not) so that is the reason if your Input_file is having ODD number of lines it will print comma(,) which is not suposed to happen.

Answer (score 3):

time for new tools! `pr` is ideal for this

```
$ pr -2ats, file

4194369,4194376
4194383,4194377
4194389,4194394
4194399,4194395
4194402,4194403
4194407
```

Comment: Why this command fails when the number before 'ats' gets bigger than 36? for example, 'pr -37ats, file' produces this message: pr: page width too narrow. The file contains more than 500000 numbers this time, instead of 11 as posted earlier.

Comment: that's when it hits the page limits. This is mostly a reporting utility, default settings are for physical constraints like the printer line lengths, etc.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk -v OFS=, '!(NR%2){print p,$0} {p=$0} END{if (NR%2) print p}' file
4194369,4194376
4194383,4194377
4194389,4194394
4194399,4194395
4194402,4194403
4194407
```

Comment: Why not awk 'NR%2{p=$0;next}{$0=p","$0}END{if(p)print}1' file

Comment: @ctac_ because that wouldn't print the last line if it evaluated numerically to zero or was blank. It also would fail in awks where the last $0's value isn't retained in the END section (the value of $0, $1, etc. in the END is undefined behavior per POSIX - only $NF is defined).

Answer (score 2):

time for old tools! `paste` is ideal for this

```
$ paste -sd',\n' file
4194369,4194376
4194383,4194377
4194389,4194394
4194399,4194395
4194402,4194403
4194407
```

Your awk could also be written as:

```
awk '(NR%2){printf "%s",$0; next}{print ","$0}END{if(NR%2) print ""}'
```